# Linq to nHibernate v3.2 - join with multiple conditions in On clause

Tags: linq-to-sql, join, linq-to-nhibernate

Doe's anybody knows how can I do join with multiple conditions in LINQ to NHIBERNATE?
Join with one condition looks like this:

```
var Query = from p in Session.Parent
   join c in child on p.id equals c.parent_id
   select p
```

My sql query is:

```
Select *
from parent t1
left join Child t2 
    on t1.id = t2.parent_id
    and t2.age > 18
```

I found a syntax of multiple conditions for LINQ to SQL and it works (I tried in LinqPad)
but when I'm trying to execute this code in nHibernate I'm getting exception:
"The method or operation is not implemented". The syntax for LINQ to SQL is:

```
var Query = from p in Session.Parent
    join c in child on p.id equals c.parent_id into pc
    from pcg in pc.Where(c => c.age > 18)
    select p.PigProductid
```

It seems that this feature is not implemented yet in LINQ to NHIBERNATE, but
maybe I'm wrong (and i hope I am).

Comment: yes, nhibernate's LINQ provider makes me sad sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to have a reference or a collection to the children in the parent class.

maybe the following could work

```
var query = from p in Session.Parent
            from c in Session.Child.Where(c => c.age > 18)
            where p.Id == c.parent_id
            select p.PigProductid;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and unfortunately it doesnt work.
About references and collections - you right, if you have those, nHibernate
knows to do join himself, but usually references are based on
one key. I want the join on more then one key. Thank u anyway...

Comment: NHibernate supports References with more than one column. i have a lot of them in my dayly work. can you post your table structure?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought about it and you right, we can set reference on more than one field.
But from what I know, reference generates inner join. Do you know if there a way to generate left join with reference?

Comment: if NH generates left join and gets a lot of null values for the child columns, what do you expect NH to do? threat it as a Child with all properties set to null or exclude the parents? for the sake of the query there is no difference